# Is there a way to change the text color in lxterminal?

Tags: linux, colors, lxde

I have a new Raspberry Pi which uses LXDE as the desktop environment in Raspbian; and the white text on black background is causing a lot of eyestrain.  I would like to change the text color to Green, but the dropdown for text options doesn't appear to allow color changes, just font changes.

Is there a way to change the text color that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LXTerminal 0.1.11, latest Lubuntu:

In menu Edit > Preferences > Style:

Top three options I'm seeing are "Terminal Font", "Background" and "Foreground". The second and third are meant for changing colors.